# appharbor not deploying static content

Tags: static-libraries, web-deployment, appharbor

I just started hosting a web application on AppHarbor, and i configured it to listen to my github repository commits.

After each commit, I see on AppHarbor the build running the tests, and deploying, but when i go to my app page, hosted on AppHarbor I don't see any images, and the js scripts are missing.

I can actually see them in the github source, but when I download the package from AppHarbor, they seem to be missing from my 'static' folder...

Anyone else run into this problem ?... Any possible causes for this ?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem -

The reason this was happening because the content wasn't being copied to the output directory. I don't know exactly how AppHarbor build there Deployment scripts, but I changed the `Copy To Output Directory` option value to `Copy Always` and this solved the problem.
(The `Build Action` was already set to `Content`)

Comment: Same problem but only with a given image (my css and js were working fine). Set image's property to copy always as you said worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the files are included in the C# project, and that their `Build Action` is set to `Content`.

Comment: I solved the problem, It wasn't exactly what you said, but thanks - You got me looking in the right direction... +1 :)